# Changing Theme.Holo on Android Manifest.xml file doesn't run on Android

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I am very new to android app development, and have recently hit a wall on the [*Styling the Action Bar page*](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Every time I change the theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` just doesn't allow the program to run on the android, with a message saying "Unfortunately, Program has stopped." every time I try to run it. Weird thing is that it saves perfectly fine on Eclipse with no errors.

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstappv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstappv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstappv2.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstappv2.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstappv2.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
06-15 21:17:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(5350): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstappv2/com.example.myfirstappv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: It's crashing with `Theme.Holo.Light` but not with `Theme.Holo`? That's strange. Please post the exception strack trace from logcat.

Comment: No no it crashes with anything Theme.Holo. It only worked with `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`, which was the default.

Comment: Ah, that's more logical. Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: I'm testing this out on Android Version 4.4.2.

How do I post the exception stack trace, if you don't mind me asking

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Oh man, you're really helping me out here haha. Here's my runtime Exception:
`06-15 21:17:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(5350): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstappv2/com.example.myfirstappv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`


I remember the article saying something about AppCompat, so I'll go check that out in the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Activity is an `ActionBarActivity` then you need to use one of the `Theme.AppCompat` variants (i.e. `Theme.AppCompat`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, &c).

From the [*Styling the Action Bar*](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) page:

> Note: If you are using the Support Library APIs for the action bar,
>   then you must use (or override) the `Theme.AppCompat` family of styles
>   (rather than the `Theme.Holo` family, available in API level 11 and
>   higher). In doing so, each style property that you declare must be
>   declared twice: once using the platform's style properties (the
>   android: properties) and once using the style properties included in
>   the Support Library (the appcompat.R.attr properties—the context for
>   these properties is actually your app).

Don't forget about the "add the properties twice" part.

Comment: How do I declare the properties in the support library?

Comment: It's explained right there in the link, when it says "For Android 2.1 and higher".

Comment: @user3743276 Haha, don't worry. Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Oops, forgot about that.